# Getting ID field while using for cycle with objects

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, cycle

what is the best way to get `for` number each time it runs?

Code:

```
fields = []

objects = otherobjects.all() 
for object in objects
    fields.append(('id_is_#', object))
```

I want to put an ID to # place. ID would be generated ++ way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fields = []
objects = otherobjects.all() 

for id, obj in enumerate(objects)
    fields.append(('id_is_' + id, obj))
```

Comment: you shouldn't use object as a loop variable its already a builtin type

Comment: @Jakob: you know I just copy-pasted and added `enum`, and as soon as I realized the mistake, I was summoned somewhere :). Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension:

```
objects = otherobjects.all()
fields = [('id_is_%d' % id, ob) for id, ob in enumerate(objects)]
```

Using 'object' as a variable name could cause problems...

Answer (score 0):

String modulation is better for this.

```
fields.append(("id_is_%s" % id, object))
```

Edit: Slight correction on the style just in case you mean something slightly differently here is a better example

```
for obj in objects:
    fields.append(("id_is_%s" % obj.id, obj)
```